# Why is sum(X, 1) the sum of the columns in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, dimensions

```
>> X = [0 1 2
        3 4 5]

>> sum(X, 1)

ans =

     3     5     7
```

`sum(X, 1)` should sum along the `1st` dimension(*row*) as per the document says:

> S = SUM(X,DIM) sums along the
>   dimension DIM.

But why does it actually sums along the `2nd` dimension(*column*)?

Answer (score 27):

In my opinion, it is perfectly consistent with everything else.

`sum(A,dim)` sums *along the direction* of dimension dim.

Rows are counted "down", so `sum(A,1)` sums "down". Columns are counted "to the right", so `sum(A,2)` sums "to the right".

Another way to look at this is that `sum(A,dim)` collapses dimension `dim` to 1 by taking the sum. Thus, a 4x3 array summed along dimension 1 collapses the first dimension, leading to a 1x3 array.

Comment: I also keep it straight in my head using the "dim is the dimension to squash" approach. Also consider arrays with 3 or more dimensions; for me, it's easier to see why it should be this way when you get away from the 2D case.

Comment: +1 for not just copy-pasting the doc (which Gtker had read but not understood) and instead explaining how to interpret it.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sum.html

> B = sum(A,dim) sums along the
>   dimension of A specified by scalar
>   dim. The dim input is an integer value
>   from 1 to N, where N is the number of
>   dimensions in A. **Set dim to 1 to
>   compute the sum of each column, 2 to
>   sum rows, etc.**

Your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: But the 1st dimension is row,and 2nd column,why it's not the case for `sum`?

Comment: Hence my "Your guess is as good as mine" - there's no real logical reason for it, so it's probably just the result of some random MATLAB developer's late-night coding session. ;)

Answer (score 2):

1 means column,
according to http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sum.html

> B = sum(A,dim) sums along the
>   dimension of A specified by scalar
>   dim. 
>       The dim input is an integer value from 1 to N, where N is the number of
>   dimensions in A. 
>       **Set dim to 1 to compute the sum of each column, 2 to sum rows, etc.**

Comment: Why it's contradictory with other context ?

Comment: It might actually be indicating the axis along which the primary iteration is occurring. (Sometimes these things are hard to understand with only low-dimensional examples.)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Matlab documentation on this is quite clear.  It states:

> B = sum(A,dim) sums along the dimension of A specified by scalar dim. The dim input is an integer value from 1 to N, where N is the number of dimensions in A. Set dim to 1 to compute the sum of each column, 2 to sum rows, etc.

You're welcome to think that Matlab is wrong, but it ain't going to change !

Comment: The offline version only mentions:`S = SUM(X,DIM) sums along the dimension DIM. ` and that's all!