# Summing across rows of a matrix instead of columns

Tags: matlab

I have a 21x19 matrix `B`

Each index of the matrix is either 1,0, or -1. I want to count the number of occurrences for each row and column.  Performing the column count is easy:

```
Colcount = sum( B == -1 );
Colcount = sum( B == 0  );
Colcount = sum( B == 1  );
```

However accessing the other dimension to attain the row counts is proving difficult. It would be great of it could be accessed in one statement. 
Then i need to use a fprintf statement to print the results to the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `sum` operates on the columns of a matrix.  You can change this by specifying a second argument to sum. For example:

```
A = [ 1 1 1; 0 1 0]; 
C = sum(A,2);
C -> [3; 1];
```

Additionally you can `transpose` the matrix and get the same result:

```
A = [ 1 1 1; 0 1 0]; 
C = sum(A');  % Transpose A, ie convert rows to columns and columns to rows
C -> [3 1];  % note that the result is transposed as well
```

Then calling `fprintf` is easy, provide it with a vector and it will produce a string for each index of that vector.

```
fprintf('The count is %d\n', C)
```

> The count is 3
>
> The count is 1

Comment: I'm going to add my traditional caveat and remind everyone that MATLAB's `'` operator is the complex conjugate transpose; you should use `.'` for the non-conjugating version.

Comment: @Edric Hey, that's "my" caveat too! I'm glad to find someone has that same Matlab "pet peeve" :-)

Answer (score 3):

The second input argument of [SUM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html;jsessionid=9125cd24d6ebd96620a8cf28c3b1) indicates [in which direction you want to sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651267/why-is-sumx-1-the-sum-of-the-columns-in-matlab).

For example, if you want to count the number of occurrences of `1` along rows and columns, respectively, and print the result using `fprintf`, you can write:

```
rowCount = sum(B==1,2);
colCount = sum(B==1,1); %# 1 is the default
fprintf('The rowCount of ones is\n%s\nThe colCount of ones is\n%s\n',...
   num2str(rowCount'),num2str(colCount))
```

Note that I use `num2str` so that you can easily print a vector.