# Sum matrix across row instead of summing position values for matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have a matrix size N by M, where:

```
matrix_1 = np.array([1, 0, -1, 0])
matrix_2 = np.array([0, 0,  0, 0])
matrix_3 = np.array([1, 0, -1, 0])
```

and the resulting matrix, after performing a function through SciPy, equals:

```
matrix_4 = np.array([2, 0, -2, 0])
```

I need to matrix such that matrix_4 (the resulting matrix) sums across arrays/rows, equaling:

```
matrix_4 = np.array([0, 0, 0])
```

I have tried `np.sum([matrix_1, matrix_2, matrix_3], axis = 1)`, to sum across rows, but that causes an error with the SciPy function I am utilizing.

Similar question in MATLAB, for reference: [Summing across rows of a matrix instead of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765563/summing-across-rows-of-a-matrix-instead-of-columns)

Comment: Can you explain the error? Does the error relate to the shape output `(3,)`?

Comment: Yes, the error relates to the shape of the arrays being of equal size to another array (not listed in this problem) to perform the SciPy function. np.sum(arrays, axis = 1) changes the shape of the resulting array.

Comment: An other typo : `matrix_1 = np.array([1, 0, -1, 0])` and did you mean `matrix_4 = np.array([0, 0, 0])` with only 3 zeros ? Anyhow please provide a complete minimal example that reproduces your issues else we'll have a hard time helping you ...

Comment: Can you actually post what your matrix is? Because the way this is phrased doesn't make sense. Is it a 2D numpy array? Or is it a numpy matrix? Or are they all separate variables like you have?

Comment: As @jadsq mentioned, your expected output is not clear. Is `array([0, 0, 0])` what you want? Because if so, `np.sum([matrix_1, matrix_2, matrix_3], axis=1)` *will* produce the desired output, and equivalently, `np.add.reduce([matrix_1, matrix_2, matrix_3], axis=1)`.

Comment: Yes, np.add.reduce([matrix_1, matrix_2, matrix_3], axis = 1) produces the desired output in cooperation with the size needed for the SciPy function. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds the code he already has ( `np.sum([matrix_1, matrix_2, matrix_3], axis = 1)`) will also produce the expected output , which is why I'm confused about his issue ...

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this as a typo, as `add.reduce` is [literally equivalent to `sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) so something else was messed up in your program.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It seems there is something else incorrect with the unnamed SciPy function I am using - my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this is your desired result:

```
In [10]: np.vstack((matrix_1,matrix_2,matrix_3)).sum(axis=1)
Out[10]: array([0, 0, 0])
```

And this is what you were getting with scipy

```
In [11]: np.vstack((matrix_1,matrix_2,matrix_3)).sum(axis=0)
Out[11]: array([ 2,  0, -2,  0])
```

Answer (score -1):

you mean like:

```
import numpy as np
a = [[1,0],[2,3]]
print(np.sum(a,axis=1)) # gives [1,5]
```

?

EDIT : i just understood your problem. you can ignore this

Comment: Yes, but I cannot sum a, as it changes the shape of the output matrix when summed along axis = 1.